# Selenium screenshot with iframe

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

im having problems in production when trying to take a screenshot with Selenium. When I successfully take the screenshot with Firefox, the texts in the iframe appear corrupted, but I can read the html source successfully, so the problem is only in the frontend. While I have no problems locally, I live in production, the project runs on an alpha Linux machine.

[image]

```
firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.headless = True
service = Service(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=firefox_options)
cookie = {
        'name': 'jwt',
        'value': '',
    }
driver.get("https://www.x.com")
driver.add_cookie(cookie)
url = "https://www.x.com/x"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
iframe = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "iframe")))
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "accept-btn-handler")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "accept-btn-handler").click()
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
time.sleep(30)
iframe_content = driver.page_source
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.save_screenshot('static/image.png')
img = os.path.abspath('static/image.png')
```

Comment: it's possible they're using the visibility API to trigger the view... what happens when you run without the headless option?